# How to express in JSON schema all or none for multiple optional properties?

Tags: jsonschema

I want to express that all or none of optional properties are present. For example

```
{
}
```

and

```
{
    "a" : 1,
    "b" : 2
}
```

should be both valid, but

```
{
    "a" : 1
}
```

and

```
{
    "b" : 2
}
```

should be both invalid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simpler way:

```
{
"properties:" {
  "a" : {"type" : "integer"},
  "b" : {"type" : "integer"}
},
"dependencies" : {
  "a" : ["b"],
  "b" : ["a"]
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here a schema that satisfies the requirements:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "a": {
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "b": {
            "type": "integer"
        }
    },
    "oneOf": [{
        "required": ["a", "b"]
    }, {
        "not": {
            "anyOf": [{
                "required": ["a"]
            }, {
                "required": ["b"]
            }]
        }
    }],
    "additionalProperties": false
}
```

An alternative would be to also express in the JSON that the properties belong together like

```
{
    "parent": {
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2
    }
}
```

where parent is either present or not and if present, then always has a and b:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "parent": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "a": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "b": {
                    "type": "integer"
                }
            },
            "required": ["a", "b"],
            "additionalProperties": false
        }

    },
    "additionalProperties": false
}
```